# Open-source packet capture apps in Android

Tags: android, open-source, packet-capture

I'm looking for open source or code example of packet capture app in android with following requirements.

- working as VPN service in android
- Can capture packets between other apps and the internet
- Using MiTM, provides SSL decode function

Comment: sslstrip android

Comment: Check out https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard as a starting point for how to implement a VPN service.
It offers this (to some extent) in a PRO version. Specifically it contains what seems to be a PCAP implementation [here](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/netguard/pcap.c%20here).